# Returning number of posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need a function to calculate the number of posts in a Wordpress blog that is aware if you are looking at a category, a given tag or the whole blog.

I'm keen to avoid rewriting for every different circumstance and want to make sure I get off on a reliable path.  Relatively new to Wordpress any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a count of all the posts in a blog, use [wp_count_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts). To get post counts from a specific category, do a count() on a call to [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with the category ID specified as a parameter.

Example:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts('category=1');
$count = count($posts);

echo $count;
?>
```

Unfortunately WordPress' wp_count_posts() function won't count a category's posts. It'll only count different post types, i.e posts, pages, drafts, and in 3.0, custom post types.

Comment: Thanks Dennis - appreciate you taking the time.  I have seen a lot of very complex solutions so a simple approach is gratefully received.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provides a template function: [WordPress › Count Posts « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/count-posts/) Could borrow the code from it and integrate it into your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: thanks - this is a great start that I can work on.  Much appreciated.